# AngularJS Controller syntax with as

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.6.9 with AngularJS Material. What I want to do is to add a menu item [basic usage](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu). The problem is that it didn't work because my structure is different.

Documentation of material says (I never seen it before):

```
angular
  .module('menuDemoBasic', ['ngMaterial'])
  .config(function($mdIconProvider) {
    $mdIconProvider
      .iconSet("call", 'img/icons/sets/communication-icons.svg', 24)
      .iconSet("social", 'img/icons/sets/social-icons.svg', 24);
  })
  .controller('BasicDemoCtrl', function DemoCtrl($mdDialog) {

  ...
```

Html:

```
<div class="md-menu-demo" ng-controller="BasicDemoCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak>
...
```

My controller's name is MainController and I don't want to change my syntax.

My js syntax is:

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$http","$rootScope", function($scope,$http,$rootScope){
...
```

How can I change the code, in order to not to change my structure of my Controller and play?

Comment: Add $mdDialog like this 
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$http","$rootScope", "$mdDialog", function($scope,$http,$rootScope, $mdDialog){
...

Comment: and config part will be in app.js file

Comment: It was the first thing I tried. What about the Html?

Comment: <div class="md-menu-demo" ng-controller="MainController" ng-cloak>

Comment: it seems is working...

Comment: I am putting answer here .....

Comment: no I tried again it works with as ctrl because in html has something like this ng-click="ctrl.redial($event)" how to replace that? You can put it as an answer that to vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include $mdDialog like

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$http","$rootScope", "$mdDialog", function($scope,$http,$rootScope, $mdDialog){
...  // order should be same.
```

And HTML

```
<div class="md-menu-demo" ng-controller="MainController" ng-cloak>
...
```

Comment: Can you edit this? One more thing. How to replace in example ng-click="ctrl.redial($event)" the ctrl if I change into MainController?

Comment: It didn't work I just put ctrl again to work. Any other Ideas?

Comment: BasicDemoCtrl as ctrl  , here ctrl is just an alias name ....not needed actually, but people use to make it short name

Comment: instead ctrl I check it with out it and with the whole name, nothing. Only with as ctrl works.